# Which weapons does the Thrill of the Hunt passive skill apply to?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

In Diablo 3, I am playing as a demon hunter. One of my passive skills is called *Thrill of the Hunt*:

[image: Screenshot]

It states, "Every 10 seconds, your bow attack will immobilize your target for 3 seconds." When this states 'bow' does that include other weapons such as the crossbow? Which weapons specifically will be affected by this passive skill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proc does not refer to which weapon is equipped, rather it refers to the type of skill you are using.

I used this passive while having a crossbow equipped and it would still proc. Also, it procs on any skill that requires "firing your weapon", which are all skills in the Primary, Secondary, and Archery categories.